# Convert script for working with multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

Lets see this script, that it's a simple carrousel

```
$script = {
   init: function(){
      this.heros(3000);
   },
   heros: function (time) {
        var t;
        var $hero = $('.hero');
        var $images = $('.hero > div');
        $hero.data('current', 0);
        var $bullets = $('<div>').addClass('bullets');
        for ( var i = 0; i<$images.length; i++ ) {
            var $item = $('<span>');
            $item.on('click', function () {
                clearTimeout(t);
                play( $(this).index() );
            });
            if(i==0) { $item.addClass('active') }
            $bullets.append( $item );
        }
        var play = function (current) {
            if(current==undefined) {
             current = $hero.data('current');
            }
            var nextMargin;
            if ( (current+1) == $images.length ) {
                nextMargin = 0  ;
                $hero.data('current',0);
            } else {
                nextMargin = (current + 1 )*100;
                $hero.data('current', (current + 1));
            }   

            $images.eq(0).css('marginLeft', -nextMargin + '%'); 
            $bullets.find('span').eq($hero.data('current')).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            clearTimeout(t);
            t = setTimeout(play, time);
        }
        $hero.append($bullets);
        t = setTimeout(play, time);
    },
}
```

The thing is that it works great, but only if there's just one `.hero` element.. if there are multiple the bullets mix up and it doesn't respect the `.length`

I know that option one should be rewrite it again, but Does anyone of you sees a quick fix that would make it reusable?

A single fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6z8n5pnq/
A multiple fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6z8n5pnq/1/

-EDIT-

I tried:

Defining a previous function, that is called on init

```
preheros: function(time) {
        var self = this;
        $('.heros').each(function(){
            self.heros($(this), time);
        });
},
```

And editing The begining of heros:

```
heros: function ($hero, time) {
        var t;
        /*var $hero = $('.hero');*/
        var $images = $hero.find('>div');
```

but no success...

any idea?

-EDIT-

GOD, it's `$('.hero').each` not `$('.heros').each` it was working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to isolate context for each `.hero` component by using `$(selector).each` function. Slightly corrected your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6z8n5pnq/2/

```
function apply($hero, time){
   var t;       
   var $images = $hero.children('div');
  //all your logic here...
}

$script = {
    init: function () {
        this.heros(3000);
    },
    heros: function (time) {
        $('.hero').each(function(){
            apply($(this), time);
        });
    },
}
```